# How can I give a WPF element a rectangular flat 3D border?

Tags: .net, wpf, border

I would like to create a rectangular 'flat 3D' look for one of my control templates.  In it's most simple version this means having a line at the bottom that is darker than that at the top, and maybe some variation between the left and right lines too.

A more complex version would allow me to provide on or more brushes so that gradients could be applied.

The default `<Border>` element in WPF lets you specify a different thickness per edge, but I can't find a way to specify multiple brushes.

So, how can I produce the effect I want as simply as possible?

**EDIT** it's been suggested that I post an example of how I want to use this.  Personally I'd be happy to have a style or a user control.  The user control might be used thus:

```
<FourSidedBorder LeftSideBrush="#00f" RightSideBrush="#0f0" ... />
```

Or perhaps even simpler:

```
<FourSidedBorder BorderBrush="#00f,#0f0,#f00,#fff"
                 BorderThickness="1,2,3,4" ... />
```

These are just ideas.  Any sensible, concise solution is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution I devised that achieves most of what I want.  It doesn't give complete control over all four sides independently, but it does give the rectangular flat 3D view that I want.

Here's how it looks:

[![][1]][1]

Paste this into [Kaxaml](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/kaxaml) to see it for yourself:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Background="#CCC">
  <Page.Resources>
    <!-- A brush for flat 3D panel borders -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Flat3DBorderBrush"
                         StartPoint="0.499,0" EndPoint="0.501,1">
      <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#DDD" Offset="0.01" />
      <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="0.99" />
      <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>  
    <!-- A flat 3D panel -->
    <Border
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource Flat3DBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" Background="#BBB">

          <!-- some content here -->
          <Control Width="100" Height="100"/>

    </Border>  
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Hope that helps someone else out.  I'm still on the lookout for innovative solutions to this problem, so keep posting and I'll accept a better answer than this one.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMStF.png

Answer (score 14):

I've done something like this just by placing multiple borders directly on top of one another.  E.g.:

```
<Border 
  x:Name="TopAndLeft" 
  BorderThickness="3,3,0,0" 
  BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}">
<Border 
  x:Name="BottomAndRight" 
  BorderThickness="0,0,3,3" 
  BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush}">
    <ContentPresenter ... />
</Border>
</Border>
```

This provides the added advantage of all the other features that border provides-- corner radius and such.

Comment: To add my $0.02, you can swap the zero and non-zero values in `BorderThickness` property above to get a sunken effect.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly probably the easiest way would be to use layering techniques. For instance create a grid like this:

```
  <Grid Width="50" Height="50">  
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <!-- Top Border -->
     <Border Height="3" Background="LightGray" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

     <!-- Right Border -->
     <Border Width="3" Background="DarkGray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />

     <!-- Content -->
     <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

     <!-- Left Border -->
     <Border Width="3" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

     <!-- Bottom Border -->
     <Border Height="3" Background="DarkGray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

  </Grid>
```

I think you get the idea. This is probably the easiest way of doing it. You could set this up as a template and use it like this:

```
<Template x:Key="My3DBorder" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <!-- Put the Grid definition in here from above -->
</Template>

<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource My3dBorder}">
   <!-- My Content Goes Here -->
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Its probably better to do this with  Line elements and and not 4 Borders

Comment: This really isn't very concise.  I'm hoping there's a better, simpler way of doing this, even after replacing borders with lines.

Comment: I'm not sure how much simpler it can be. How about you post an example of how you want to use it, and we'll work backwards from there.

Comment: Throw it into a user control and it will be really simple to use.

Comment: Imagine I wanted to have several of these in my UI.  Laying this XAML around every instance would really obscure the logical tree.  How could this visual tree specification be separated?

Answer (score 2):

you can reference the **PresentationFramework.Classic** assembly and then use

```
<Window xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic">
...

<Grid Width="50" Height="50">
    <mwt:ClassicBorderDecorator BorderThickness="3,3,3,3"/>
</Grid>
```

I was using [this technique for looking at control templates](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/03/19/How-can-I-decompileextract-a-WPF-Controls-default-template-as-Xaml.aspx) to see how default buttons were styled

Answer (score 2):

Needed a classic 3D 'inset' border.  Based on @GregD's answer (thank you!):

```
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrush}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush}">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}">
                ..
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Border>
```

To make it an 'outset', revert the order of 1st and 2nd element pairs.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for cool approach that I prefer - using shadows too (as a style, so you can use It anywhere):

```
  <Style x:Key="border_style" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="1" Color="#FF2686AA" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
         </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropShadowEffect}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.2,1.2,0.3,0.3"/>
    </Style>
```

Usage (when you register your styles):

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource border_style}">

 </Border>
```

Position of 3D border effect Is done with BorderThickness. And you can play with colors, ShadowDepth,BlurRadius, CornerRadius etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" x:Name="Border" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1 1 0 0" BorderBrush="White"/>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="#696969"/>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1 1 0 0" BorderBrush="#E3E3E3" Margin="1"/>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="#A0A0A0" Margin="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DimGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```