# 3D borderBrush style - wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to make same 3D border as on the picture:

[image]

I need just borderBrush of this control.
Could you help me with this? I'm not strong in brushes creating. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581838/how-can-i-give-a-wpf-element-a-rectangular-flat-3d-border

Answer (score 2):

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FF505050">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>
```

Although it is preferable to use a style, for "cleanness" sake and in case you need to reuse the brushes etc.

Comment: No, this is no what i need. I need the same gradient as on the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It just needed another border around the previous example to get what you were after.

Update the colours accordingly.

```
<Border Height="60" Padding="5" Background="#FF505050">
    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF505050">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="DarkSlateGray" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
</Border>
```